# Mean and Variance of the Weibull Distribution

Tags: probability

The density of the Weibull Distribution is given by:
$$f(x) = \alpha x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x^{\alpha}}$$

The Gamma function is defined as:
$$\Gamma(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x} \,dx$$

Show that $E(X)=\Gamma(\frac{1}{\alpha}+1)$ and $Var(X)=\Gamma(\frac{2}{\alpha}+1)-\Gamma^2(\frac{1}{\alpha} + 1)$

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I've actually solved it. I posted it for anyone interested in solving it. Proof should be about less than 10 lines.

Comment: Just a heads up, that's the density for a Weibull with scale parameter ($\beta$) equal to 1. A more general p.d.f would be $\frac{\alpha}{\beta} \left(\frac{x}{\beta}\right)^{\alpha - 1} \exp\left\{-\left(\frac{x}{\beta}\right)^\alpha\right\}$, $x \geq 0$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For constant $k$, we have the following
$$E(X^k)=\int\alpha x^{\alpha+k-1}e^{-x^\alpha}dx$$
Using substitution $u=x^\alpha\Leftrightarrow x=u^{1/\alpha}$ results in $$du=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}dx \Rightarrow dx=\frac{du}{\alpha x^{\alpha-1}}=\frac{du}{\alpha u^{\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha}}}=\left(u^{\frac{1}{\alpha}-1}\right)\frac{du}{\alpha}$$ leading to
$$\begin{align}E(X^k)&=\int\alpha \color{blue}{x^{\alpha+k-1}}\color{red}{e^{-x^\alpha}}\color{green}{dx}\\&=\int\alpha \color{blue}{u^{(\frac{k}{\alpha}+1)-\frac{1}{\alpha}}}\color{red}{e^{-u}}\color{green}{\left(u^{\frac{1}{\alpha}-1}\right)\frac{du}{\alpha}}\\&=\int u^{\left(\frac{k}{\alpha}+1\right)-1}e^{-u}\ du\\&=\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{\alpha}+1\right)\end{align}$$
Thus the mean is
$$E(X)=\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}+1\right)$$ and the variance is
$$Var(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2=\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{\alpha}+1\right)-\Gamma^2\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}+1\right)$$

Comment: can you explain your substitution? I am actually working on this problem and this is where I am struggling

Comment: @AlyssaWallace Please see edits to my answer. By way of explanation, I have added a few more lines and some colouring.